# Masking in logback.xml with all request and responses

Tags: spring, logging, request, logback, masking

I am using logback.xml to mask sensitive data for logging which works fine

```html
<appender name="DATA_MASK" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
       <layout class="com.masking.MaskingPatternLayout">

          <maskPattern>\"creditCardNumber\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern> <!-- questionCode JSON pattern -->
          <Pattern>${logback.detailedroot}</Pattern>

       </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

But the problem is that this custom MaskingPatternLayout does not catch the request-response log when I turn on the request-response config in logback.xml

```html
<logger name="Request" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="Response" level="DEBUG" />
```

As we know, the two configs above help us catch all requests and responses as logs. However, the masking pattern does not work for them.
Any way the handle these request-response logs to mask.